# Is there a best practice to add context to stream elements?

Tags: java, java-stream

I'd like to add context to elements of a stream. I know I can map to a List containing the element and the context to add, but it seems kind of bloated (computation / memory overhead) and not flexible enough (types are lost). I know I can do something like this:

```
public record Tuple<A, B> (A a, B b) {}
```

And then, for example:

```
stream // Stream<Foo>
    .map(foo -> new Tuple<>(foo, getContext(foo)); // Stream<Tuple<Foo, FooContext>>
```

But is there a best practice or maybe even a standard implementation with little overhead?

Comment: Can't FooContext just keep track of the element that was passed to him ?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but I don't understand where the "bloat" is. Apart from class `Tuple` you have two lines of code. Are you asking how to achieve this **without** having to declare class `Tuple`?

Comment: In the Java 15 world I'd use a record instead of a Tuple, giving you nicely named accessors for each part.

Comment: @Abra Yes, I try to do it without having to a declare ```Tuple``` class. To give an example of bloatedness, instances of ArrayList usually keep an overhead of free array spaces, hence somewhat bloated. While you can circumvent that via ```Arrays.asList(...)```, it still feels like there should be a better way to do it.

Comment: @azro That context might be an object of a class that I can't modify, so not always an option. But thanks for your suggestion :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to create that `Tuple` class.

You can use, for example, `java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`:

```
stream.map(foo -> new SimpleEntry<>(foo, getContext(foo)))...
```

I wouldn't call that a standard implementation, but I always prefer to use a JDK class when one is available.